# How to edit specific files in /Library folder on Mac with Apple Sandbox?

Tags: cocoa, appstore-sandbox

From Apple's documentation, I didn't understand if there's any way to get pre-approved entitlements to edit files in a specific folder located in the system /Library folder, without asking the user to choose this specific location via NSOpenPanel or similar.

I don't mind, and would actually like, to ask for the user's credentials to make such a change, at specific points in the application's lifetime; but letting the user choose which folder to modify just doesn't make sense in my case.

Comment: What files are you trying to modify then?

Comment: Also, you can elevate privileges for an app: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html. To update system files, it seems like `authopen` might be the right approach - it's a way to open a file in a privileged process and get back a pipe to read/write from.

Comment: As I wrote, I want to modify files in the /Library folder. The API you mention apparently doesn't work in sandboxed applications, as is written in your own link and here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/authorization_concepts/02authconcepts/authconcepts.html

Comment: I'm fairly certain that Mac App Store apps that access system folders without a user action are intentionally impossible. Either sacrifice sandboxing and app store compliance, or use the open panel. I'm actually somewhat certain the user only needs to open the folder you need to modify **once**, and your app can retain the permission for all its subfolders persistently. (The Movist movie player does that to list directories and autodetect multiple episodes of a TV series. It *might* not hold for write access but then again it might also work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it - the application needs a [File Access Temporary Exception](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AppSandboxTemporaryExceptionEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH5-SW7) entitlement.